# Share test verifier in various test modules with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm completely new to python testing and currently run into the following problem using pytest:

I have a around 20 different types of objects (Let's call them A, B, C, ...) and I want to create a separate test-module (test_a, test_b, ...) for each of them. After playing around with the tests I found out that the final verification function is identical for each object, so I refactored the code into a class and put this into a separate module (Lets call it utils.py):

```
import pytest

class Verifyer:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Lots of state variables, limited to 2 for simplicity
        self.obj1 = None
        self.obj2 = None

    def verify(self, line_1: str, line_2: str):
        # Lots of comparisons based on internal state ...
        assert line_1 == "Hello, World"
        assert line_2 == "Goodbye, World"


@pytest.fixture
def verifier():
    return Verifyer()
```

In my test module (here only for test_a.py) I can the do the following:

```
from .utils import verifier

def test_a_essential(verifier):
    line_1 = '*A XYZ                                                     %'
    line_2 = '*A XYZ                                                       %'
    verifier.verify(line_1, line_2)
```

In principle, this all works, but as soon as the test fails, I do not get any detailed error-information (even with -vv). If the string comparison fails I only see the following message:

```
    def verify(self, line_1: str, line_2: str):
    # Lots of comparisons based on internal state ...
    >       assert line_1 == "Hello, World"
    E       AssertionError
```

As soon as I inline the content of utils.py into test_a.py the error-message looks like this:

```
Expected :'Hello, World'
Actual   :'*A XYZ                                                     %'
```

Is there a possible way to share the verify method among all 20+ test modules? If not, I can only copy+paste the code 20+ times or throw all tests for each object type into one big test module. Both options seem highly unattractive to me.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_plugins.html#assertion-rewriting

Comment: You can define your `Verifyer` class in a `conftest.py` file and it will be available in all other pytest modules: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session

Comment: @Tzane I already found that documentation and I almost did it the way it is described there (my module is named utils.py and not conftest.py). The essential difference is that the assert statements must be part of utils.py (or contest.py) - otherwise I have to write the assert over and over again. But if I do that, I end up with the issue I described above.

Comment: Oh my gosh - the name must actually be conftest.py, is that possible? Just by renaming the file, I get the behaviour I actually want. Sorry, I really didn't get that from the documentation.

Comment: @MarkusMoll Yes! Sometimes the devil is the details ;)

Comment: @MarkusMoll the thing is `conftest.py` is the name reserved by pytest. It should store fixtures and hooks (or even local pytest plugins). Note that you may have multiple `conftest.py` files across your test packages. You don't need to import fixtures which are defined in conftests (the only requirement here is to have `__init__.py` files on the way to conftest files because it may affect `PYTHONPATH` in an unexpected way).